# Failed to start Network Time Synchronization

Tags: linux, date, embedded, time

Can anyone let me know why I am facing `Failed to start Network Time Synchronization` at the kernel logs?

When I run `timedatectl` command I get the message

```
Failed to query server: Connection timed out
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific: Which distro are you using? Which `ntpd` is used? How does the `ntpd` config look?

Comment: The `Connection timed out` error message would indicate the `timedatectl` command made an attempt to query some time server but got no response at all. To troubleshoot, the first thing you'd need to figure out is, which time server it was trying to contact? Have you manually configured any time servers to use, or is it getting a time server address from a DHCP response? The next questions would be, is that time server address reachable, and does it make sense to use that time server? Are there firewalls blocking access to that time server, or is there another server that you should be using?